# vba method range of object error

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to highlight the duplicate zip codes with font color Red in column L, from L2. I did some research online and modified the codes accordingly but they are not working properly.

I used **F8** and it stopped at the line y = Worksheet... I  tried to add the word **Application.** in front of WorksheetFunction but it is giving me the same error.

```
Sub test()
    Dim x, y, LR22 As Long
    Dim zip As Worksheet

    Set zip = Worksheets("Zip")
    LR22 = zip.Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row


    For x = 2 To LR22
        If zip.Cells(x, 12) <> "" Then
            y = WorksheetFunction.Match(zip.Cells(x, 12), zip.Range("L2:L" & L22), 0)
            If x <> y Then
                zip.Cells(x, 12).Font.Color = vbRed
            End If
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Change `L22` to `LR22`.  And add `Option Explicit` as the first line of your code module - that will force you to declare all your variables, and therefore notifies you when you make a typo like this.

Comment: Thanks but now the whole list is in red..

Comment: Well that is a completely different question - that is "why does the current cell's value always exist in a range including the current cell" and can probably be fixed by testing that `x <> y + 1`.  (It's early morning, and I am still drinking my coffee, but I think that's the reason.)

Comment: Thanks this makes sense now. And it works great!

Comment: The suggestion of @YowE3K to add `Option Explicit` is almost indispensable for writing reliable VBA code. You can do it once and for all by enabling `Require Variable Declaration` in `Tools/Options/Editor` in the VBA editor.

Comment: You should also undo the color change on `Else` of `If x <> y + 1 Then`.

Comment: @JohnColeman `Option Explicit` and indenting make for debuggable code. [Rubberduck VBA](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) will do both for you. ;-)

Comment: corrected your formatting

Comment: _Must_ you use VBA? If this is Excel 2003 or newer, select your column of ZIP codes, select `Home` | `Conditional Formatting` | `Highlight Duplicates` and select your color pattern (text & background), _et voila!_ all your duplicate ZIP Codes are highlighted without a lick of VBA. (NOTE: menu selections are for 2010, may be different in other versions of Excel)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without code. Sort column L, then add the conditional formatting formula A1=A2. This will highlight duplicate entries in consecutive cells.

Comment: This will work when the list is ordered by zipcode. Changing the formula to include a match function may do the trick though.